# Какое имя задать логерам питона?

Tags: python, логирование

Подскажите, какое имя задать логеру подключаемого модуля?
Я так понимаю лучший вариант, чтобы логер вызываемого модуля наследовал вызывающий, т.е. чтобы наследование выполнялось через точку в имени. Мне такой вариант подходит.
Как автоматически сгенерировать эти имена логеров?

upd: Мне нужно чтобы в вызывающем модуле я определил логер, например, с записью в конкретный файл, и остальные модули чтобы писали в этот же файл

Т.е. есть ожидаю примерно такую картину:

main.py

```
Import pack1
logging.getLogger('main')
logging.info('test1')
pack.def1()
```

pack1.py

```
def1():
   logging.getLogger('main.pack1')
   logging.info('test2')
```

Вывод:

```
test1
test2
```

Comment: А вы знаете зачем нужны имена логгеров? Кст, туда можно передавать и `__file__`...

Comment: Конечно знаю, чтобы задавать уникальность, или чтобы наследовать свойства, о чем я написал. Мне нужно чтобы в вызывающем модуле я определил логер, например, с записью в конкретный файл, и остальные модули чтобы писали в этот же файл. если использовать _ _file_ _, то это не будет работать.

Comment: Я в таких случаях делал модуль `common.py`, в нем создавал логгер и импортировал его во всем модули, которым нужно логи писать

Comment: А вот для меня лучший вариант как в Nlog (.net) - есть логгеры, есть таргеты (куда писать) и отдельно! есть правила связывающие сообщения каких логгеров куда направить вида "main.* уровня INFO туда то".